# Construct a circle

Tags: geometric-construction

Circles *a* and *b* intersect at M and N.
Construct a circle *k* orthogonal to Circles *a* and *b* and touching third given circle *c*.

Problem is supposed to be solved using inversion and/or power of a point.

Since *a* and *b* intersect at M and N and *k* is supposed to be orthogonal to them we can conclude that center of *k* belongs to radical axis of *a* and *b* which is a line through M and N.

If the radical axis goes through center of a circle *c* I think that problem then becomes : construct a circle orthogonal to two given Circles which contains a given point (which I know how to construct)

But what happens if this isn't the case?

I hope this makes sense (English isn't my native).

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint** What happens if you invert the whole picture using an inversion around (a circle centered in) $M$ or $N$?

Comment: Thanks, I get it now